# Fast-growing hierarchy and Turing machines

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Is it possible to get an estimate of the size of a Turing machine computing $f_\alpha(n)$, for a given $\alpha$ (I am especialy interested in moderately large $\alpha$ like the ordinal of Fefferman-Schütte, or the small Veblen ordinal)? The idea is to get an idea of the size of the BusyBeaver function $BB(n)$ for moderate values of $n$, as the litterature usually only mention the exact known values (for $n\le 6$) and the fact that such values will probably never be known for $n=10$, say.

Comment: A reminder of the meaning of $f_\alpha$ in this context would be welcome.

Comment: I believe $BB(15)$ is known to be uncomputable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine#Smallest_machines --so by moderate, I assume you mean $7 \le n \le 14$, no?

Comment: @Lee: The fast-growing functions are defined on wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy - note the dependency on the choice of ordinal notations.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by BB(15) uncomputable (it would imply that the Halting problem could not be solved for some 15-states (and 2 symbols) machines, no?) But this  obviously does not mean that BB(15) is "incomprehensibly large", to quote Friedman : it could well be that actually BB(15) is smaller than Graham number, say, but simply we will never be able to prove it... So what I am trying to do is to prove, for instance, that BB(15) is greater than $f_{\epsilon_0}(15)$ (which is already quite large, if ridiculously smaller than TREE (3)), just by constructing a suitable Turing machine..

Comment: @Steve, theoretically BB(15) *is* computable, it is just a finite number. I guess you mean uncomputable in practice.


Comment: If α was a recursive ordinal we could use K(α)+c as an upper-bound. I don't know what can be said when α is not recursive, can we even find an algorithm to compute it or is its existence a non-constructive (which might mean that we cannot give any number as an upper-bound)?

Comment: I am not sure of that : can you give an estimation for $\alpha=\epsilon_0$ ? And, of couse, the fast-growing hierarchy is defined only for recursive ordinals, and not even all of them (as there is no uniform way of defining ordinal notations up to the Church-Kleene ordinal)

Comment: You're interested in "moderately large α", but anyway I will mention the posting at https://sites.google.com/site/res0001/surpassing-graham-s-number which concerns *the least n such that Σ(n) > Graham's number*.

Comment: The algorithm would use the definition of $f_{\epsilon_0}$ to compute it by a recursively algorithm. The description of the algorithm would be some fixed code for computing $⟨\alpha,n⟩\mapsto f_\alpha(n)$ and the description of α. So the total code would be some constant + $K(\epsilon_0)$.

Comment: But this fixed code is not clear at all... Actually, I couldn't even write a (reasonably short) program computing ⟨α,n⟩↦fα(n) in a higher-level language like Maple, say, even using the recursive facilities they give...

Comment: It is not that difficult (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy#Definition), it is a recursive function that uses the ordinal notions, the only non-trivial case is when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and one has to compute $\alpha[n]$. So if we write the function that maps $\langle \alpha,n \rangle \mapsto \alpha[n]$ the rest is easy.

Comment: The link to `sites.google.com` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/267525) above seems to be broken, but a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509222047/https://sites.google.com/site/res0001/surpassing-graham-s-number)

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Gödel's speed-up theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_speed-up_theorem) which discusses sentences like "this sentence is unprovable in theory T with less than $\phi$ symbols" where $\phi$ is some computable formula like TREE(3), and T is some consistent, effective theory like PA or ZFC with large cardinals (assuming those are consistent).  Call the above sentence S.

Per the speed-up theorem, S is both true and provable (see the wiki article).  The provability means that for reasonable theories, there is a relatively small $n$ such that an $n$-state Turing machine will eventually (by unbounded search) find the proof and halt, but that the running time will be (much) longer than $\phi$.  Of course BB(n) has to be even bigger than that.  With a suitable encoding, n=15 might be enough.  So BB(n) quickly dominates any computable formula that can be written down.

"BB(15) is uncomputable" could be interpreted something like: there is a 15-state TM that halts if and only if your favorite strong arithmetic theory T is inconsistent.  So if you believe that T really is consistent, that means you'll never be able to know what BB(15) is.